# jQuery .val(#) does not change selection following AJAX call - works if debugging/paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectlist

I have an interesting issue - when I perform an AJAX call that refreshes this Appointment List dropdown with new entries based on either page load or a filter that is entered - the .val() method will *not* set

This is what success of the AJAX method will do - basically it sets back up the AppointmentList dropdown with new entries:

```
                    $.map(data, function (item) {
                        $('#AppointmentList').get(0).options[$('#AppointmentList').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.AppointmentTime, item.ID);

                    });
```

This is what calls the function which basically just contains the $.ajax() method that re-populates the #AppointmentList dropdown. When I get the new set of values back - I still need it to have the old "appointment" pre-populated.

```
            var tempVal = $('#AppointmentList').val();
            DropDownList();
            $('#AppointmentList').val(tempVal);
```

This does nothing, and the first element in the list re-created is selected.

*However* if I put a breakpoint on :

```
$('#AppointmentList').val(tempVal);
```

Then it seems enough time has passed for this dropdown to be able to be changed - if there is a breakpoint and I continue - the dropdown will change back to the value I want it to be if I am debugging the Javascript.

Any ideas on how to refactor this? I've been thinking maybe when we actually do the $.map() function we can set our old value up there - but this code seems to work... should I have a bit more time between when the Ajax finishes and I need to set the .val() again.

Comment: if setting a breakpoint makes it work temporarily, you likely have the page reloading or something similar, such as not understanding the asynchronous nature of ajax and callbacks.

Comment: If you're getting a value asynchronously then anything that relies on that value must either be handled in the `success` call or alerted from the `success` call. Otherwise, you're just hoping that the timing is right.

Comment: Mmm~ Asynchronicity... I will taste it soon.

Comment: Nice - well then my hunch was right that I need to refactor this to be in the success instead of following the execution. Hence - asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask a dumb question - figure out a dumb answer - I guess. Asynchronous. Duh.

Move those two lines to where this one is above the $.ajax() call:

```
var tempVal = $('#AppointmentList').val();
```

Then, put the line that sets the value *within* the success, but *after* the $.map():

```
$('#AppointmentList').val(tempVal);
```